# Python: Difference between 'global' & globals().update(var)

Tags: python, variables, global

What is the difference between initializing a variable as `global var` or calling `globals().update(var)`.

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When you say

```
global var
```

you are telling Python that var is the same var that was defined in a global context.
You would use it in the following way:

```
var=0
def f():
    global var
    var=1
f()
print(var)
# 1  <---- the var outside the "def f" block is affected by calling f()
```

Without the global statement, the var inside the "def f" block would be a local variable,
and setting its value would have no effect on the var outside the "def f" block.

```
var=0
def f():
    var=1
f()
print(var)
# 0  <---- the var outside the "def f" block is unaffected
```

When you say globals.update(var) I am guessing you actually mean globals().update(var).
Let's break it apart.

globals() returns a dict object. The dict's keys are the names of objects, and the
dict's values are the associated object's values.

Every dict has a method called "update". So globals().update() is a call to this method.
The update method expects at least one argument, and that argument is expected to be a dict. If you tell Python

```
globals().update(var)
```

then var had better be a dict, and you are telling Python to update the globals() dict with the contents of the var dict.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Here is the original globals() dict
print(globals())
# {'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__file__': '/home/unutbu/pybin/test.py', '__doc__': None}

var={'x':'Howdy'}
globals().update(var)

# Now the globals() dict contains both var and 'x'
print(globals())
# {'var': {'x': 'Howdy'}, 'x': 'Howdy', '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__file__': '/home/unutbu/pybin/test.py', '__doc__': None}

# Lo and behold, you've defined x without saying x='Howdy' !
print(x)
Howdy
```

Comment: Ok so, if I had a variable declared in a method, and in that method called globals().update('var':'0') only during the first run of the script, I wouldn't be able to use 'var' in the same way as a variable that has been declared as "global var", throughout the rest of the code upon the second execution of the script?

Comment: globals().update('var':'0') should be globals().update({'var':'0'}). This will affect the global variable 'var', even if this command was put inside a method. The behavior of these commands is the same on every run of the script. If this does not answer your question, please post your code so we can get a better understanding.

Comment: Ok, it's short but the formatting will be weird:
try:
     i+=1
except NameError:
     i=0

. That code will be in a main method, and I can't change it, or add any method declarations before the code / outside of the method. What I can do is add code in the main method after this little code snippet. I need to make 'i' act as a global variable, so that it will increment by '1' on every successive script execution.

Comment: @frank: Please ask this "What I can do is add code in the main method after this little code snippet?" question as a separate question with enough details that it is a stand-alone question and reasonably clear.

Comment: are there any differences between `global var = value` and `globals().['var'] = value`?

Comment: It is 10x better to discover things for yourself than to fed an answer. Please try this yourself. I'm sure you'll discover the answer.